# Transform sub-queries to joins

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have three tables: `userProfile`, `loginTimes`, `orders`.

I am trying get each user's profile row, his last login time, and his last order row.

Here's my query:

```
Select u.*, t.loginTime, orders.* From userProfiles u 

Inner Join

(Select userId, MAX(time) loginTime From loginTimes Group By userID) t

On u.userId = t.userID

Inner Join
(Select userId, MAX(enterDate) orderDate From orders Group By userId) o

On u.userID = o.userID

Inner Join 
orders On orders.userId = u.userId And orders.enterDate = o.orderDate
```

Is there any way to rewrite without so many sub queries?

Comment: In the above query you're not doing anything with o.orderDate, because you select orders.*, is that correct?

Comment: Ahh I see what OP must be trying to do. Pull the user record with last login + the entire order row with the MAX(enterDate). His query of course does not do this though.

Comment: That might be the requirement yeah, but not exactly developed that way.. :)

Comment: I am now using the max orderdate

Comment: You have tagged this question as both `mysql` and `sql-server`, please  correct this since it cannot be both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP I think this is the query you are going for, this still requires 2 subqueries, but I don't believe your original query functioned as intended.

You could remove the `loginTimes` subquery, and use `MAX(loginTime)` in the outer `SELECT` list, but then you'd need to `GROUP BY` every field in the `order` table, which is arguably just as unclean.

The following query retrieves the `UserId`, latest `LoginTime` and the entire `order` record for the user's most recent order:

```
SELECT u.userId, 
       u.userName,
       l.loginTime,
       o.* 
FROM userProfiles u 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT userId, 
                   loginTime = MAX(time) 
             FROM loginTimes 
             GROUP BY userID) l ON u.userId = l.userId
INNER JOIN ( SELECT *,
             rowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userId 
                                         ORDER BY enterDate DESC) 
             FROM orders) o ON u.userId = o.userId AND o.rowNum = 1
```

[Working on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82bf2/1/0)

Comment: Bah, just noticed you've tagged this question as both `mysql` and `sql-server`, this query only works for `sql server`

Comment: a sql-server solution will do.

Comment: Funny if you look at this.. that the original question was: Is there any way to rewrite without so many sub queries?

Comment: Sometime you need to ignore the question entirely to find the right answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do:

```
SELECT u.userID
      ,u.otherColumn
      ,MAX(t.time) AS loginTime
      ,MAX(o.enterDate) AS orderDate
FROM userProfiles u
JOIN loginTimes t ON t.userID = u.userID
JOIN orders o ON o.userID = u.userID
GROUP BY u.userID, u.otherColumn
```

For every other column in userProfiles you add to the SELECT clause, you need to add it to the GROUP BY clause as well..

**Update:**

Just because it can be done.. I tried it without any subquery :)

```
SELECT u.userID
      ,MAX(t.time) AS loginTime
      ,o.*
FROM userProfiles u
JOIN loginTimes t ON t.userID = u.userID
JOIN orders o ON o.userID = u.userID
LEFT JOIN orders o1 ON o.userID = o1.userID AND o.enterDate < o1.enterDate
WHERE o1.orderID IS NULL
GROUP BY u.userID
        ,o.* --write out the fields here
```

You'll have to write down the fields of the orders table you want in the `select` clause in your `GROUP BY` clause also.

Comment: There were some .* in the original query.  That makes the original intent by the user confusing ...

Comment: I was hoping for a query like this.  However, I need all the rows from `orders`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily re-write the aggregation with the following.

```
-- Aggregation 

(
SELECT
  T.userId, 
  MAX(time) as loginTime,
  MAX(enterDate) as orderDate
FROM
  loginTimes as T INNER JOIN orders as O
ON
  T.userId = O.userId
GROUP BY 
  T.userId
)
```

However, I do not understand why you are calculating MAX(enterDate) and not using it.

The two tables that are joined without aggregation is easy also.  You should stay away from using *.  It is just wasted overhead if all the fields are not being used.

```
SELECT 
  U.*, O.* 
FROM 
  userProfiles as U
INNER JOIN
  orders as O 
ON O.userId = U.userId
```

Please explain what you are trying to return as values from the Query.  **What is the business logic?**